# Laravel Show method is not getting anything to display

Tags: laravel

calling show method

```
<td><a href="/pages/{{$page->id}}">{{$page->pages}}</a></td>
```

This is my controller

```
 public function show(Posts $posts)
{

    //$id = $posts;
    //dd($id);
    return view('dashboard.demo',compact('posts',$posts));

}
```

When I try to dd() I got this

```
  Posts {#227 ▼
  #fillable: array:13 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Laravel Show method is not getting anything to display  this is only i got while i used dd function

Comment: Please post your route definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fix your compact function like this-

```
return view('dashboard.demo', compact('posts'));
```

I have removed the **$posts** as that is not needed in the compact as you already defined the **posts** in the function.

Now, make sure your route resembles something like this-

```
Route::get('pages/{posts}', 'YourController@show');
```

If you use any other variable than **posts** then your **show** page will not work. Method parameter and route parameter name should match.

If you are using **Route::resource()** then I am sure that your routes are generated like this -

```
Route::get('pages/{pages}', 'YourController@show);
```

In that case, you need to change your method like this-

```
public function show(Posts $pages)
{
    return view('dashboard.demo', ['posts' => pages]);
}
```